# python re.match() doesnt return expected result

Tags: python, regex

I am attempting to select part of a python string using re.match:

```
revenue = "Revenue;;Item,Johnver,Vanston,Danbree,Vansey,Mundyke;Tea,190,140,1926,14,143;Coffee,325,19,293,1491,162;Water,682,14,852,56,659;Milk,829,140,609,120,87;;Expenses;;Item,Johnver,Vanston,Danbree,Vansey,Mundyke;Tea,120,65,890,54,430;Coffee,300,10,23,802,235;Water,50,299,1290,12,145;Milk,67,254,89,129,76;;"
revenue = re.match(r"(?<=Revenue;;).*(?=;E)", file_content)
print(revenue)
```

but it returns `None`.

I tested the regular expression on regex101.com, and it gave me the desired match, the text following `Revenue;;` and preceding `;Expenses`:

```
Item,Johnver,Vanston,Danbree,Vansey,Mundyke;Tea,190,140,1926,14,143;Coffee,325,19,293,1491,162;Water,682,14,852,56,659;Milk,829,140,609,120,87;
```

Therefore I'm assuming something is wrong with my python implementation, however, I couldn't find any information in the python regex documentation that helped me. Tried with both python 2 and 3.

What could I be doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `re.search`

**Ex:**

```
import re

revenue = "Revenue;;Item,Johnver,Vanston,Danbree,Vansey,Mundyke;Tea,190,140,1926,14,143;Coffee,325,19,293,1491,162;Water,682,14,852,56,659;Milk,829,140,609,120,87;;Expenses;;Item,Johnver,Vanston,Danbree,Vansey,Mundyke;Tea,120,65,890,54,430;Coffee,300,10,23,802,235;Water,50,299,1290,12,145;Milk,67,254,89,129,76;;"
revenue = re.search(r"(?<=Revenue;;).*(?=;E)", revenue)
print(revenue.group())
```

**Output:**

```
Item,Johnver,Vanston,Danbree,Vansey,Mundyke;Tea,190,140,1926,14,143;Coffee,325,19,293,1491,162;Water,682,14,852,56,659;Milk,829,140,609,120,87;
```

Answer (score -1):

Per Python documentation

> re.match(pattern, string, flags=0)
>
> If zero or more characters at the **beginning** of string match the
>   regular expression pattern, return a corresponding match object.
>   Return None if the string does not match the pattern; note that this
>   is different from a zero-length match.

So you should probably use either `re.search` or `re.findall`

Answer (score -1):

`re.match` starts matching from the beginning of the string, so a look-behind `(?<=...)` at the start of a string would never match. As @Rakesh have mentioned, use `re.search`